# Optimize curl speed

Tags: php, performance, curl, optimization

How can I optimize the speed of this curl?

```
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,  '');
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 180);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close ($ch);
```

I have tried adding this.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
```

And I have read that it should help out a lot, but I don't see any difference. Do I need to put it somewhere specific?

Or do you guys have any other idea of how I can optimize this?

Comment: The speed of the response is down to the other site. If that site is slow there is nothing you much to be done

Comment: That is true, but I know for a fact that it's possible to optimize it on my end as well.

Comment: There really isn't much you can do on your end. You can for IPV4 or prevent redirects but in the end, the response time is mostly controlled by the server performance. cheers

Comment: Hey @EmrikAhlström are you did any measures or request time, did you try to check timings of your actual request via proxy for example? I would recommend you the only option I know that could actually make difference to request time https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL.html also https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS.html can make some change since there would be no any overhead during request execution

Comment: Should it look like this then? ```curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);```

Comment: @EmrikAhlström right, did you try so far? Any difference? Btw when you answering to someone in comments use nickname highlight, otherwise users don't see your replies.

Comment: @Liastre Oh yes sorry. No it didn't make any noticable difference. I guess it's the other site that is the problem.